# Which terminal emulator is used in my tty1?

Tags: emulation, virtual-console

I see that `xterm` - a popular terminal emulator designed for the X Window System - is used in my DE, lxde.

```
echo $TERM
xterm
```

Now I switch into tty1 with <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd>.

```
echo $TERM
linux
```

Does this mean that a terminal emulator program named linux is using in tty1?

Comment: It is actually the Linux Console and it is internal to the Kernel:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_console

Comment: LXDE uses LXTerminal; xterm is rarely used these days.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly. This means that tty1 is using the 'Linux' terminfo file of which defines the capabilities of the terminal:

> For every (well almost) model of terminal it tells application
>   programs what the terminal is capable of doing. It tells what escape
>   sequences (or control characters) to send to the terminal in order to
>   do things such as move the cursor to a new location, erase part of the
>   screen, scroll the screen, change modes, change appearance (colors,
>   brightness, blinking, underlining, reverse video etc. --[Source](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Text-Terminal-HOWTO-16.html)